# PYTHONPATH is not set correctly by source devel/setup.bash

Tags: ros, pythonpath

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having some issues with the PYTHONPATH that is set by my ROS environment.

my .bashrc contains the following lines:

```
source /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash
source /home/x/workspace/devel/setup.bash
```

If I print my PYTHONPATH in a new bash it looks like this:

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/x/workspace/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

The **PYTHONPATH** contains only workspace-specific packages.

This results in failure, when trying to import the catkin package from a python interpreter (as it is for example required when importing a rosnode project in qtcreator)

I investigated this problem a little bit, and it seems as if the first sourcing command sets the

```
PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/jade/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

(which is where the catkin package is found)
The second sourcing command however resets the path, and only appends the workspace specific part again.

Is this the intended behavior?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223477/pythonpath-is-not-set-correctly-by-source-devel/setup.bash/) by [martin1412](https://answers.ros.org/users/25296/martin1412/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2016-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't really know what the problem was, I removed the whole workspace and set it up again.
It seems to work now

---

Originally posted by [martin1412](https://answers.ros.org/users/25296/martin1412/) with karma: 46 on 2016-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0